# Change font color inside TD Table / P text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I got problem to change font color inside td table. Because the **p** is auto generate PHP framework in my page.

Here's sample of my html code.

```css
p {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px red;
    font-size: 140%;
}

.gtext {
    color: blue;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue;
    font-size: 140%;
}
```

```html
<td class="gtext">
<p>Example of Font Color</p>
</td>
```

As you can see **P** has own red color CSS, but I'm gonna change it to **blue color**, how to make it?

Is there another way to change color inside of that **TD table** which is **P** inside?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this would do it:

```
.gtext > p {
    color: blue;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue;
    font-size: 140%;
}
```

Comment: This will also not work because DOM will not read <td> tag without <table> tag so this css won't apply

Comment: It works, Thank you. I just posted direct question straight to the point, thats why I just entered TD without table. cause Table and TR and TH have their own css, I didnt want to make complicated. anyhow thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
.gtext p {
    color: blue;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue;
    font-size: 140%;
}
```

Comment: This will also not work because DOM will not read `<td>` tag without `<table>` tag so this css won't apply

Comment: Wanna bet? https://jsfiddle.net/t4fuet4s/  My guess is you should read the question again. He mentioned he has a table.

Comment: first i dont assume the codes by my self i believe in what he write and second if there is a table tag there is no need to do any change in css...i can even bet

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
  <td class="gtext">
    <p>Example of Font Color</p>
  </td>
</table>
```

You are using `<td>` independently but it should come in `<table>` tag. No css change required just put `<td>` inside `<table>`

Comment: Sorry,Unfortunately, it seems that we have the same answer , then you you have answered , while I was writing the same answer

Answer (score 1):

it work if td is inside tr and tr inside table,because html parser escape td if it out of table,may be your code doesnot generate table and tr

```css
p {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px red;
    font-size: 140%;
}

.gtext {
    color: blue;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue;
    font-size: 140%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="gtext">
<p>Example of Font Color</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<!-----Without Table---->
<td class="gtext">
<p>Example of Font Color</p>
</td>
```

Comment: It happens...but your answer is also perfect so i vote for urs.